# Can I remove an app that I've bought from my account and re-purchase it again?

Tags: google-play-store, uninstallation, paid-apps

To thank the developer on Steam you can repeatedly buy games as gifts or remove them from the account and re-buy them again (I think it still works).

How to do a similar thing on Google Play Store?

Comment: Nowadays repurchasing apps should not be necessary as most apps provide some sort of time limited in-app purchase options which you can buy multiple times once the configured time span is over.

Answer (score 1):

App purchases are [tied to the account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/134097135?hl=en&msgid=134099831). You can't re-use that account to buy again. Create a different Gmail account , add it your device and buy from that account (you can use the existing payment method set up for the main Gmail account you had set up)